# Install clojure with leiningen on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: clojure, leiningen

So I go to clojure.org/downloads and it says I can get clojure via leiningen. Great. I go to leiningen.org and think I'm following the instructions. It says to get their bash script and put it in your ~/bin/ Did it. Make it executable. Did it. ...then what? run the script? It doesn't say, but I did. This creates a .lein , which I suppose it should. Now what? How do I now install clojure? This is what clojure.org/downloads says:

```
Modify the dependencies and repositories sections of your Leiningen project.clj file, specifying the version of Clojure that you want:
; under dependencies, select the release of clojure
; (and optionally clojure-contrib) that you want
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure
                "1.5.0-alpha5"]]
```

but I have no idea what that means since I find no "project.clj" file anywhere. ~/.lein/self-installs has a monster leiningen-2.1.3-standalone.jar file, which probably doesn't want me hacking on it. What should I do now? How could I better inform myself in the future?

Answer (score 11):

At this point `lein` should be in your path. So, typing `lein` or `lein help` at your shell prompt should bring up the task list.

To create your first project

```
lein new my-first-project
cd my-first-project
```

You should then see a `project.clj` in that directory. Edit the dependencies in that file if you wish to have a different Clojure version than the default. Then just enter the REPL and any dependencies (including Clojure) should be downloaded and installed for you.

```
lein repl
```

As you your last question, I'd follow the tutorial on the leiningen website immediately after completing the installation instructions.

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md

Comment: I now understand that what I downloaded was lein itself, not an install script. So yes, the `lein new my-first-project` ran -- and running `lein repl` seemed to do some sort of downloading too ... of what? Is clojure now somewhere on my system?

Comment: @user78162 The Clojure jar should now be in your maven repository, typically something like `~/.m2/org/clojure/...`. Ordinarily you would not use the Clojure jar directly, but through `lein`. If you get a prompt from `lein repl` then you are ready to start learning Clojure interactively. Refer back to the tutorial on how to do builds.